# SOLID principles in swift, using an Encryption Class

Tags: swift, class, encryption, solid-principles

I was reading up on the SOLID principles of class design and wanted to test something using a simple Encryption class. Below is what I have come up with. Basically, I want to create a encryptor class, which takes  input a string and the encryption method to use. I have come up with the following but I do not quite like how I have to pass instances of the specific Caesar class. What happens if there is another encryption method, but uses different inits? Could you please show me the best way to achieve this while keeping code clean, flexible and satisfying the SOLID principles? Your help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Update: I do understand that the implementation that I have for Caesar is not robust and needs improvements in it self. However, at this stage, I am more concerned about the solution design.

```
import Foundation

 protocol Encryptor{
     func encrypt(st:String)->String
     func decrypt(st:String)->String
}

class Encrypt {

    var str: String
    var encryptedstr: String?
    var encryptionMethod:Encryptor
    var decryptedString:String?

    init(strtoEncrypt:String, encryptionMethod:Encryptor){
    self.str = strtoEncrypt
    self.encryptionMethod = encryptionMethod

    }
    func encrypt(){
        print("encrypted original string \(str)....")
        self.encryptedstr = encryptionMethod.encrypt(st: self.str)
        print("the encrypted string is \(encryptedstr ?? "" )")
    }

    func decrypt(){
        self.decryptedString = encryptionMethod.decrypt(st: self.encryptedstr!)
        print("the decrypted string is \(decryptedString ?? "") ")
    }

}

class Caesar:Encryptor{

    let shift: Int
    init(shiftValue: Int){
        self.shift = shiftValue
    }

    func encrypt(st:String)->String{
        var encryptedStr = ""

        for char in st.utf8{
            let shiftedChar = Int(char)+shift
            let encryptedChar = Character(UnicodeScalar(shiftedChar)!)
            encryptedStr = encryptedStr + String(encryptedChar)
        }

        return encryptedStr

    }

     func decrypt(st:String)->String{

        var decryptedString = ""

        for char in st.utf8{
            let shiftedChar = Int(char)-shift
            let decryptedChar = Character(UnicodeScalar(shiftedChar)!)
            decryptedString = decryptedString + String(decryptedChar)
        }
        return decryptedString
    }

}

let caesar = Caesar(shiftValue: 1)
let enc = Encrypt(strtoEncrypt: "test is the best", encryptionMethod:caesar)
enc.encrypt()
enc.decrypt()
```

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. Yes I understand that the details of the implementation need improving and fixing. But I am more concerned about the overall design approach that I have taken. Is there a better way to achieve what I am trying to do? Thanks

Comment: Choosing encryption is probably a poor choice given the large differences of common methods.

Comment: Choose 3/4 different concrete encryption algorithms and try to see if you can come up with a better abstraction. I you can't then perhaps there's no point in trying to have a generic encryption service.